# collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld' compilation terminated

Tags: gcc, c++, c, g++

When I try to run C and C++program I am getting

```
collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld' compilation terminated.
```

I have already installed GCC and G++ latest version.

Comment: you need libc6-dev. Do `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev` and if gets installed (if it's not already installed), try compiling your C/C++ programs again

Comment: libc6-dev is already the newest version (2.23-0ubuntu3). But no joy yet

Comment: What do `gcc -print-prog-name=ld`, `which ld` and `dpkg -V binutils` say?

Comment: gcc -print-prog-name=ld   show ld , which ld= /usr/bin/ld , dpkg -V binutils = blank

This is nginx issue because when I switch to apache it seems fine

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had this resolved with a workaround:

On the cross-compiler bin dir I made a symlink pointing to the compiler

```
ld (ld -> powerpc-fsl-linux-ld).
```

Then in the makefile or build script I added the toolchain folder to the PATH variable

```
export PATH=$PATH:"toolchain-dir-absolute-path"
```

it worked!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! In its current form your answer is not as good as it could be. Could you review [How to Write a Good Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659), and [Style guide for questions and answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/89/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Our team got the same error when building RHEL6 DTS2 via [AFL](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/afl/). We solved this using GNU linker instead of [gold linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(linker)) to which CMake seems to default.

In your compiler command lines, lookout for `-Wl,-fuse-ld=gold` and get rid of it!

In our CMake buildsystems this worked by invoking the build scripts with additional option `-DCOL_WITHOUT_GOLD`.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the gold linker via `apt-get install binutils-gold`.

For me, that still gave errors, as binutils-gold installs a /usr/bin/ld.gold, and via strace, it appears gcc wants a binary named with the full host triple, e.g. x86_64-nptl-linux-gnu-ld.gold.  I had to symlink it `ln -s /usr/bin/ld.gold /usr/bin/x86_64-nptl-linux-gnu-ld.gold`, and then all went fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!! For lld I had to do the following: `ln -s /usr/bin/lld-8 /usr/bin/ld.lld`

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, my `/usr/bin/ld.bfd` permissions did not allow read or execute for all users.  `chmod a+rx /usr/bin/ld.bfd` fixed my problem